# Neo4j 1.9.5 (using spring data neo4j) query time slow

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a neo4j community edition 1.9.5 running in an ec2 m1.medium instance (around 4gb ram) . I have around 300 nodes, 800 relationships and some 2000 properties. Neo4j is running in REST mode. Below is my applicationContext.xml :

```
<beans profile="default">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase" id="graphDatabaseService">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/"/>
        </bean>
        <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
</beans>
```

Now,  I have this query below, which shows all the movies which your friends have liked, which takes like ~10 seconds to return ! :

```
start user=node(*)
            match user-[friend_rela:FRIENDS]-friend,friend-[movie_rela:LIKE]->movie 
            where has(user.uid) and user.uid={0}
            return distinct movie,movie_rela,friend
            order by movie_rela.timeStamp desc
            skip {1} " +
            limit {2}
```

I have indexed the following things:

My Indexes in the adming UI shows I have indexed the following :

Nodes:

```
movieId (from Movie)
__types__
Movie
uid (from User)
User
```

Relationships:

```
IsFriends
Like
__rel_types__
timeStamp
```

I have also changed the neo4j-wrapper.conf file to have the following heap sizes

```
# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=512

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=2000
```

Do you think I am missing anything. Wondering why it takes so long ! Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query is horrible inefficient, it basically traverses the full graph multiple times. You should use a index lookup to find the start point for your query and then traverse from the start point(s) - so you're doing a local query instead of a global one:

```
start user=node:Movie(uid={0})  
match (user)-[friend_rela:FRIENDS]-(friend)-[movie_rela:LIKE]->(movie) 
return distinct movie,movie_rela,friend
order by movie_rela.timeStamp desc
skip {1} limit {2}
```

Comment: ah ! wasnt aware of the node index based queries. I was trying with the same thing on cypher, but wasnt able to get it right. My user node has an indexed property of uid and was trying 
start user=node:User(uid=12345) return user; but is throwing up an 'String Literal or Parameter expected"

Comment: use: `start user=node:User(uid='12345') return user;`

Comment: The index 'User' didnt work, I have an index on uid, with the name 'uid' . This works, but is still in the order of 8 seconds :( :

start user=node:uid(uid={0}) match user-[friend_rela:FRIENDS]-(friend)-[movie_rela:LIKE]->movie return distinct movie,movie_rela,friend order by movie_rela.timeStamp desc skip {1} limit {2}

Comment: start user=node:User('uid:1234') return user; returns nothing though. You think something is wrong with the way I am indexing ? #ThanksForYouTime

Comment: does `start user=node:User(uid='1234') return user;` return something? Is a second invocation of the 8s statement faster?

Comment: This does not return anything : neo4j-sh (0)$ start user=node:User(uid='1234') return user; My uid is of type long and it is not allowing me to do a User(uid=1234). And no, I tried multiple invocations, even restarted my server/neo4j. Still gives me around 8s

Comment: since your using SDN, please post your User class' source code and verify which indexes you currently have using "index --indexes" in neo4j-shell

Comment: User class source : http://pastebin.com/RyJGu3EG 
Indexes : http://pastebin.com/qy2j4Jqk

Comment: `start user=node:uid(uid='1234') return user` or `start user=node:uid('uid:1234') return user` giving something?

Comment: then use this part for start and append the rest of the statement from my initial answer

Comment: thats what I tried : start user=node:uid(uid={0}) match user-[friend_rela:FRIENDS]-(friend)-[movie_rela:LIKE]->movie return distinct movie,movie_rela,friend order by movie_rela.timeStamp desc skip {1} limit {2} , its still in the order of 8secs

Comment: how fast is it when removing `distinct` and `order by`?

Comment: Removing distinct didnt quite make a difference, but removing order by  did. Brought it down to 2 or 3 seconds. I have indexed the timeStamp for the Like relationship. You think I should do something else ?

Comment: Stefan, do you think I need to re-model ? Order by LIKES is on of my primary usecases. Not sure why that is adding to so much time, even though timestamps inside LIKE is indexed. All timestamps are stored as a Long. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57545/discussion-between-paypalcomp-and-stefan-armbruster).